# css print query not working

Tags: css

I have this code in my main CSS file but when I print preview it isn't hiding the contents.

```
@media print {
#nav,
#footer,
#flash {    display:none; } }
```

When I add a linked print stylesheet it works as it should.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What browser are you using? Its probably because the browser doesn't support this way of declaring print styles.

I would advice to *stick to the best practice* (if you can) and use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" type="text/css" />
```

More info [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/mediatypes).

Comment: Using FF 4. Strange. I will stick to the good ol way of doing it as suggested. Just wanted to reduce that one HTTP request.

Comment: Still having this issue in Chrome 38. So yeah, print styles need to have the `media="print"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you do not have the media="screen" attribute in your link to your stylesheet. That will cause it not to apply when printing.
either add 'print' to the attribute media="screen, print" or leave the attribute off completely

see http://lawrencenaman.com/optimisation/print-media-queries-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

"The browser support for media queries is surprisingly decent. For the queries in this particular demo (utilizing min and max widths), current version of Firefox, Safari (including Mobile), Chrome, and Opera are all supporting it. Internet Explorer 9 will be supporting it, but 8 and below do not. If I wanted to deliver the best possible experience in IE 8 and below, I'd either fake it with JavaScript like I did in this article, or use an IE specific stylesheet and style it in the same style as the most common browser width according to analytics.

Note that milage may vary on individual types of queries. For example, the iPhone supports the width queries but does not support the orientation queries. The iPad supports both."

-- excerpted from http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/